# plot.ts in R: Why most par()s don't work in it?

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering why most of the `par()`s such as `font.lab ; font.axis ; cex.lab` even `xlim()` don't work with `plot.ts()` in R?

Any suggestion as to how to make `plot.ts()` accept `font.lab ; font.axis ; cex.lab ; xlim` effects?

```
coin_outcome <- sample(x = c(0, 1), size = 20, prob = c(1 - .6, .6), replace = TRUE)

plot.ts(cumsum(coin_outcome) / 1:20, ylim = c(0, 1), font.lab = 2, font.axis = 2, 
cex.lab = 2, xlim = c(1, 20))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Use par in this situation and it work for me.

```
coin_outcome <- sample(x = c(0, 1), size = 20, prob = c(1 - .6, .6), 
 replace = TRUE)
 par(font.lab=3,font.axis = 2,cex.lab = 2)
 plot.ts(cumsum(coin_outcome) / 1:20, ylim = c(0, 1),
 xlim = c(1, 20))
```